# Powershell 2.0 Windows Server 2008 SP2 update does not apply to your system

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I am trying to install Powershell 2.0 on a Windows Server 2008 SP2 box.  According to the Microsoft download page, I need KB968930-x86.msu.  I have downloaded that, but when I try to install it, I get "Update does not apply to your system".

Can someone let me know which file I need to download to get Powershell 2.0 on 32-bit Server 2008 SP2?

Thanks

Comment: Check the Powershell version first: > $psversiontable.psversion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/how-to-determine-what-version-of-powershell-is-installed

Answer (score 1):

You may have already installed it.  Go into Programs/feature and add a windows component.  Look for powershell, check it to complete install.

Heres the link for the Win mgmt framework.  Pick the correct install from the bottom of the page and follownthe install instructions
[WimMgmt KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929)

Comment: I am running Windows 2008.  There is no option to add a windows component in Windows 2008.  I looked in features in server manager and Powershell 1 is installed, but I'm trying to install Powershell 2.0.  Please let me know how to install Powershell 2.0 on Windows 2008.  Thanks.    EDIT:  I tried installing Powershell 2.0 without version 1.0 installed and got the same results.

Comment: In added a link to the correct download page.

Comment: If you go to that link, it will tell you to download KB968930-x86.msu.  This is the file that tells me "Update does not apply to your system".

Comment: This article suggest you go to Add/Remove programs and click show updates.  Then uninstall KB926139.  After removing it, try reinstalling the update.  http://powershell.com/cs/forums/p/2977/3998.aspx

Comment: There is no software named KB926139 on my system to uninstall.  This article suggest that Powershell 1 needs to be uninstalled.  I get the same error message with or without it installed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue may occur in case when certain new Windows update(s) are installed before installing PowerShell 2.0.
I had the same problem (with 64 bit version though) after installing Windows Internal Database Service Pack 4 for x64 Edition (KB2463332).